# c++ bulid message shows a reference argument while i pass arguments by value

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm using the GNU GCC Compiler under Code::Blocks.

```
    int foo(long s){cout<<"long"<<endl;return 0;}
    int foo(float s){cout<<"float"<<endl;return 0;}

    int main()
    {
        double a(3.2);
        foo(a);
        return 0;
    }
```

I know this will trigger ambiguous error, but the build message is telling me

```
error: call of overloaded 'foo(double&)' is ambiguous
```

I did pass the arguments by value of a double variable never by a reference as writen above.

And whenever I use a const double :

```
foo(3.2);  // enclosed in main function
```

The build message tells me error like this:

```
error: call of overloaded 'foo(double)' is ambiguous.
```

Wonder why this is happening.

Isn't the passing process not the same between a double variable and a const double?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get `call of overloaded ‘foo(double)’ is ambiguous` with g++ 4.6.3. Are you sure you don't have a foo(double&) defined somewhere ?

Comment: @otibom: The code is too simplified, he probably uses a `double` variable as parameter, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15410142/1139697

Comment: sorry, i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
foo(3.2);
```

the compiler doesn't know which one you are referring to - the "3.2" could cast to either a float or a long.

If you make the call:

```
foo((float)3.2);
```

it works. Or cast to long, if you want.

Your question appears to be why the error is about the double& - it is because your double variable most closely matches with an overload of foo(double&).

I think you are confusing the type - double - with a **variable** of type double. Look at the differences in these two examples:

```
foo(3.2)
```

Here the compiler is telling you that there is no overloaded method that takes a 
**double type**

```
double a(3.2);
foo(a);
```

In this one, you are actually passing in the variable, but since there is no overloaded function where you can pass in a variable of type double (that is, double&), it tells you that there is no overloaded method that takes a **double variable**, or a double&.

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: That's not what he's asking.

Comment: Actually, it was exactly what he was asking, at least before the question was edited. The ambiguous call is because the 3.2 is a  double, and the compiler can't decide whether to cast the double in foo to a long or a float. Please remove the downvote.

Comment: Sorry I can't remove it, SO says it's been more than an hour. "You last voted on this answer
1 hour ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited"

Comment: I don't see why that double variable is mostly matched with an overload of `foo(double&)` instead of an overload of `foo(double)` like what's with the literal argument in `foo(3.2)`    (so sorry for my poor English)

Comment: It is because you are passing into the function a variable of type double - which would most closely match with double& (a reference to an actual variable of type double)

If you pass in an actual double (3.2) it matches with foo(double), because there is no variable - just a literal of type double.

Comment: Here is what I really don't understand that the variable I passed in is explicitly a double while its exact match is `foo(double&)` instead of `foo(double)`. And as to the literal argument, it being a const double while it tells me the exact match is `foo(double)` instead of a more perfect one `foo(const double)`. I think it's because for some efficiency reason, it's better to set pass argument by reference so `foo(double&)` is the perfect match. But what about the literal?

Comment: When you explicitly pass the variable, you are passing in a variable - so the closest match is foo(double&), which implies a variable - if you have a reference, you have a variable.

If you pass in a double (albeit a const literal), the closest match is foo(double).

Comment: And the literal is NOT a const double - it is a literal, which is CAST to a double, not a const double. Maybe that answers your question?

Comment: Big thanks for your patience and everything. I think I get it now.

Comment: At [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/), it says:  The default type for floating point literals is `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `foo(long)` nor `foo(float)` perfectly fit your parameter. Since `double` can be converted implicitly too both `long` and `float` the call is ambitious.

You can either provide an additional overload for `double` or use an appropriate parameter type.

Note that your example is **too simplified**. The following code would trigger your error message:

```
double bar = 3.2;
foo(bar);
```

This is because `bar` is a lvalue and the perfect match would be a `double&`. Still, if you provide a `foo(double)` overload it will merely accept this function.

Comment: You mean it's because the compiler is trying to compile `bar` as `double&` when there is no perfect match for a double lvalue ?

Answer (score 1):

`foo(3.2)` is passing a double, so the compiler doesn't know if you mean the `long` or `float` version of `foo` to be called.

I don't think I'd read too much into the error. The compiler is telling you a possible type that it has detected given call site, but the reference would decay if there was a function to call that matched `foo(double)`.

As well as providing an overload for `double`, you could make the literal a `float` by using `3.2f`

Answer (score 1):

From this tiny bit of code I can't tell why he is giving you that specific error. I tried to recreate it but only got it without the &. Can you show the whole code or a bigger example that has the same error?